Schema not accessible implicitly on dev DB
I've got 2 databases, one for production and one for development.
On production I can run
select * from [mytable] -- and query [myschema].[mytable] without specifying the schema

but on the development DB the same is not true
select * from [mytable] -- Invalid object name 'mytable'

What can I do to have the schema accessible implicitly?

SELECT schema_name, schema_owner
FROM information_schema.schemata
where schema_name = 'myschema'




schema_name
schema_owner




myschema
dbo



I know this is not good practice but it's not my code and I don't have control over it, this accessibility problem is causing some bugs.
versions

Microsoft sql server, 13.0.6435.1 the production server
Microsoft sql server, 16.0.1000.6 the development server –


Microsoft sql server, 13.0.6435.1 the production server
Microsoft sql server, 16.0.1000.6 the development server

Did you try change user's default schema in dev? ALTER USER user_name WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = myschema

Will I not lose default access to dbo this way? I need to have both

No you won't. One more question. Did you try SELECT * FROM [db_name].[myschema].[mytable] in both server?

nope, I selected SELECT * FROM [mytable] in both servers, while using the correct db

SELECT * FROM [db_name].[myschema].[mytable] works for both of them if it's what you meant

On a side note, you are behind on updates for both servers.

lol, yeah, it's not really up to me unfortunately

@mbielsa I just get back Cannot alter the user 'myadminaccount', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I'd also want the change to be effective on all users

that account is sysadmin

If the user you mentioned has 'sysadmin' privilege, it should be performing this operation. I think you forget to use use database_name syntax. You have to perform this alter query on your db not in master database

No, I'm using the right DB :/
